# How to call Foreman puppet api from another web application?

Tags: puppet, foreman

I am trying to call foreman API from other different domain. But always getting cors origin error. Using ajax and angular but both send the same error.

Actual error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> ‘https://192.168.x.xxx/api/v2/config_reports/1914’ from origin
> ‘http://localhost:4200’ has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn’t pass access control check: No
> ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ header is present on the requested
> resource.

Angular code:

```
public getReport(){
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT',
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('admin:Test123@')
      })
    };
    return this.httpClient.get<object[]>('https://192.168.8.137/api/v2/config_reports/1914', httpOptions); 
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found solution. So I have to set cors with `foreman-installer`.

```
foreman-installer --foreman-cors-domains http://localhost:4200 /* Your domain name*/
```